# When compiling, "Incorrect function" error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to build a VS 2010 web project and I'm getting this error:

Could not write to output file 'C:\Users\me\myProject\obj\Debug\myProject.dll' -- 'Incorrect function.'

I've tried everything from reinstalling to editing folder permissions to running visual studio as system to moving it to a different folder and nothing resolves this error.  Has anyone seen it before, or know what to do about it?

Comment: I can't create any file named myProject.dll in that folder, or rename any file to myProject.dll, or copy a file named myProject.dll to that folder.  Other names work fine.  This is bizarre.

Comment: Something maybe has a lock on it. Could be antivirus software. Try restarting Windows.

Comment: I've restarted over a half a dozen times.  It doesn't fix it.

Comment: And the answer is...  antivirus!  Windows decided that myProject.dll was malware.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes antivirus software "decides" that the .dll or .exe that we are building is malware. Many such apps also have some sort of a white-list of files for which you can tell the antivirus to ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error in VS 2022 after upgrading from .NET 7 to .NET 8.

Oddly, *renaming the project* fixed it, **until** I switched the name back.  I had two other developers download the code to see if they had the problem.  They did not, so the issue was only on my local machine.  I restarted Visual Studio, but that didn't work.  Then, I ended up emptying the **bin** and **obj** folders for the project, then **restarting** Visual Studio.  I also read that some people had luck when the rebooted their machine--like it was holding onto an old reference, or a cached file.