# .net Windows Compiler Not Working Properly

Tags: .net, compiler-errors

Good Morning Guys,

I would like to ask as i have a problem with my .net Compiler and it is not creating an executable file once i have cleaned and rebuilt the whole solution. the error i am getting is as follows

Could not write to output file 'STMobilePC.exe' -- 'Incorrect function. '.

is there any missing steps that i might have overlooked? i have checked the output folder and the settings i have for the output folder and all seems corrrect. i am only having a problem with the compilation in Debug mode but not in release mode. hope you guys could help me out on this

Best Regards,

Noel Isip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When compiling, "Incorrect function" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743403/when-compiling-incorrect-function-error)

Answer (score 0):

You should check if any running antivirus program is blocking you, since you are creating a dll or .exe file which most of the malware programs finds it suspicious.

Comment: Much Thanks. I have allowed it on my antivirus system but still i am having the same error. is there any other place i could look for to change a setting for this error?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar compilation issues (Visual studio not being able to write the output exe/dll). This may be caused by file locks on the output file (you compiled it before and compiler can't overwrite it).

You should check for antivirus software finding your executable suspicious or, as it happened for me, check if a previous version is running or stuck in a loop. Sometimes, opening the task manager and closing the .vshost.exe forcefully then attempting to debug also solves the problem.

See similar question at [When compiling, "Incorrect function" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743403/when-compiling-incorrect-function-error)

Comment: Thanks Yuri, as of now i have no access on my Local Antivirus Software as there is a third party people who is currently taking care of our hardware components. i have brought this to their attention and will let you know any development on this inquiry. i do have a same situation before that i encountered and i have known that letting the .DLL or .Exe pass through the antivirus corrects this Issue. again many thanks to your help guys

Comment: Thanks guys, The Third Party People who handles our Local hardware noticed that the .dll's and .exe's are being prevented from building and compiling in the .net compiler. Many Thanks to all of you guys for helping me on this one

Best Regards,